# C++ - Spawnvp inside executable started by _popen or CreateProcess

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm developing a web application using the Wt framework in which I want to execute another executable (C++ console app) after pushing a certain button. This executable prepares some text files, and then sends some ftp commands to sync these text files with other servers. These ftp commands are executed using the _spawnvp command. When using the executable as a standalone app, everything works perfectly; when starting it using either _popen or CreateProcess, it does everything correctly, except for the _spawnvp command which is not being executed correctly. Is there any explanation why this does not seem to work?

Thanks in advance!
Best regards,
Bert

Comment: Wild guess: it uses relative file paths,  and thus depends on the current directory. Which directory this is, depends on the launch method. With `CreateProcess`, you pass current directory as one of the arguments.

Comment: Completely right! Thanks for your solution